# Dynamic metadata using Tridion Delivery Framework (TDF) in 2011?

Tags: 2011, content-delivery, upgrade

We are upgrading our CMS from 2009 into 2011. In the 2009 we were using the TDF (Framework) to generate dynamic metadata by adding comments in our CP and let the deployer use that to create the metadata on the delivery server to be consumed by the broker.

This was possible by updating the `cd_tdf_conf.xml` under the metadata section to specify the tag used in the CP to identify the custom metadata and then updating the `cd_deployer_conf.xml` by replacing the original processor with:

```xml
Processor Action="Deploy" Class="com.tridion.profserv.deployer.MetaDataProcessor"
```

However, this functionality doesn't seem to be supported anymore in 2011, I can't find the tdf jar files or config files, and when trying to deploy the ones from 2009 I get an error (which makes since!)

Is there an alternative to the above functionality in 2011?

whether using the TDF framework or any other solution, is there a way to create dynamic metadata (at publishing time)?

Comment: You need to get the latest CWA framework and config. Open a ticket with Customer Support. CWA is changed a lot and lot of stuff rolled into core product.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TDF is a commercial extension by Tridion Professional Services and an optional part of CWA (which was also a commercial extension).

CWA is now available as a Tridion Product, but the TDF remains a Professional Services extension. You may have to contact Tridion PS for an updated copy of this framework (and may have to pay for it too).

Comment: Thank you for the information Nuno, I will contact Tridion support as you suggested and find out if we can get the TDF extension. However, can you help me with the other part of my question, is there a way to create dynamic metadata (other than TDF - with built in Tridion API)?

Comment: All the TDF does (with regards to this functionality) is to parse the content of the pages and component presentations you publish and search for a pattern for the metadata, insert those values as custom meta of the current object then remove it from the published item. It's really not more complex than that, you could recreate this functionality quite easily in a custom deployer extension.

Comment: I'm accepting Nuno's answer since it put me on the right direction to solve my issue. I contacted Tridion support and they were able to provide me with an updated version of the TDF framework that is supported by Tridion 2011.