# Pushing custom Page metadata during publishing

Tags: 2013, content-delivery, query

I have a Page inherited from top level Publication, which I should not localize, but at the same time I would like to (somehow) add metadata info to the Page during Page publishing (at that point I can determine what metadata the Page needs) and latter to query Pages on the CD side by that metadata.

Something similar to how `RenderedItem` metadata works for deployer/storage except I would need metadata information to be accessible for querying using CD API.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something like this was done before through the use of a Metadata Processor extension in CWA and the Tridion Delivery Framework, where the additional data was made available as part of the item and then in a storage extension moved to the metadata before saved in the Broker.

See also: [Dynamic metadata using Tridion Delivery Framework (TDF) in 2011?](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/2772/dynamic-metadata-using-tridion-delivery-framework-tdf-in-2011)

And I know that there are plans to create an extension point on the content delivery side, allowing you to populate the Broker metadata of an item at publish time. But at this point, there is nothing available for you, so you will have to build your own customization for this.